# Haskell Parser Combinators - identifiers

Tags: parsing, haskell, parser-combinators

I am trying to write my own parser combinator library in Haskell, and I am struggling with how to parse identifiers.
I have a datatype defined as follows which will be part of my AST.

```
data Expr = Var String | .... deriving (Show)
```

The purpose of this expression is to hold the names of variables as I parse them. The parser is defined as follows:

```
identifiers :: Parser Expr
identifiers = do
  first <-  string "_" <|> alphanum
  rest  <-  many alphanum
  guard $ notElem (first:rest) keywords
  return $ Var (first:rest)
```

I was wondering where in the parsing do you take into account what value the identifier is bound to. For example, if you had `number_of_results = 5`, the parser will parse the name of the identifier, but how do you keep reference to what the value of the identifier is?

I was initially considering redefining the data type as follows:

```
data Expr = Var String Value | .... deriving (Show)
```

and then, in the parsing stage, continue parsing until I get to a value.

However, I am not too sure whether I should do it like this... Could someone suggest a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the parser's job to figure out what the value of an expression is — that's the job of the *interpreter*. The parser's job is merely to turn a wedge of text into something easier for an interpreter to work with.

In this case, you'd probably do something like

```
data Expr = Assign String Value | Var String | ...
```

You may or may not want to distinguish between *expressions* (which just produce a result) and *statements* (that do flow control and so on). It depends how complicated the language you're trying to parse is.

You may also want to change this to `Assign String Expr`, since you can (presumably?) assign the result of an arbitrary *expression* to a variable, not merely a constant like 5.

Once you've built a parser that turns text into this structure, then writing an interpreter that "executes" the program as another, separate, task.

Comment: ah i see, thank you. Quick qs, i was wondering why in your definition for the Expr data type, you have the Var value constructor, what purpose does it serve? I was under the impression that if you had a statement like x = 5, the parser will convert it in to something like  (Assign x (Int 5)). Is your var case for variable declarations that do not have a binding initially, e.g x; ?

Comment: @Zubair What does "5 + x" parse into?

Comment: ah i see, assuming we have the relevant data types defined, i would assume something of the sort : BinApp Add (Lit Int 5) ( Var x), thank you for the clarification.

Comment: random sidenote, why cant I @ you?

Comment: @Zubair The author of the question or answer you are commenting on always gets notified and are assumed to be the target of a comment by default, so adding an @ for them is considered redundant.